# Nginx domain if contains name

Tags: nginx

I want to know if possible to set server names with 5-6 domain in 1 directive.

For example:

```
 server_name
*.google.com
*.google1.com
*.google2.com
*.google3.com
*.google4.com
*.google5.com
```

My question is like this
Can i make

```
 server_name
*.google*.com #This will include google1.com google2.com google3.com
```

is it possible?

Comment: Not like that, but you could try regular expressions. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

Comment: i try. not working ^google([0-9])\.com any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here solution

```
 server_name
"~^google(\d{1,3}+)\.com"
*.facebook.com
*.twitter.com
```

~^google will start with google and (\d{1,3}+) will include numbers.